# Проброс портов. Настройка соединения к VisualSVN Server

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, ip, port

Попытался поднять VisualSVN Server для нужд себя и своего напарника, однако, возникла проблема, которая ставит меня в тупик.

При подключении к серверу по внешнему IP и порту с устройства, находящегося в локальной сети роутера всё проходит нормально.

[image: Подключение с устройства в локальной сети]

Однако, когда мы по этому же IP и порту пытаемся подключиться с устройства, не находящегося в локальной сети - выдаёт ошибку: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. То есть, в сущности, сервер просто не даёт ответа.

Порты на роутере проброшены, статический DHCP компьютеру-хосту выдан на роутере, WAN IP роутера соответствует информации с 2IP, ping с удалённым компьютером ходит в обе стороны, Traceroute не показывает каких-либо промежуточных точек между внешним IP (роутером) и компьютером-хостом, сервер слушает порт, брандмауэры на компьютере и на роутере на время тестов отключены.

Роутер - INNOBOX E80

Провайдер - Ростелеком

OS хоста - windows 10

[image: переадресация портов]
[image: IP WAN роутер]
[image: 2IP]
[image: Tracert]
[image: TCPView]

Буду рад любой помощи, поскольку сам сейчас не имею ни малейших предположений в чём проблема, кроме, разве что, того, что провайдер искусственно запрещает хост Apache серверов без покупки статичного IP. Но это звучит больше, как теория заговора.

Я понимаю, что есть вариант добиться результата с использованием систем вроде hamachi, однако, хотелось бы по возможности обойтись без них.